# Campo Lista de um jsp

Tags: java, spring

Este campo é preenchido corretamente por uma consulta feita no DAO.

O problema é que não está aceitando o objeto como nulo ou como o valor pelo ID.

O campo da entidade é

Meu [entity](/questions/tagged/entity)

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cos_id_id")
    public CosifEntity getCosif() {
        return cosif;
    }

    public void setCosif(CosifEntity cosif) {
        this.cosif = cosif;
    }
```

Estou com este erro do log do eclipse.

`Field error in object 'cosifEntity' on field 'cosif': rejected value []; codes [typeMismatch.cosifEntity.cosif,typeMismatch.cosif,typeMismatch.br.com.netsoft.desif.model.desif.federal.CosifEntity,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [cosifEntity.cosif,cosif]; arguments []; default message [cosif]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'br.com.netsoft.desif.model.desif.federal.CosifEntity' for property 'cosif'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [br.com.netsoft.desif.model.desif.federal.CosifEntity] for property 'cosif': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]`

O jsp está assim para este campo:

Meu [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp)

```
<select class="chosen-select form-control" id="cosif" name="cosif" data-placeholder="Selecione uma COSIF">
 <option value=""></option>
 <c:forEach var="contaSuperior" items="${listaContaSuperior}">
 <option value="${contaSuperior.id}">
 ${contaSuperior.numeroNome}</option>
 </c:forEach>
</select>
```

O que pode ser ?

Comment: Como converter o registro escolhido para a classe antes de persistir.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi o problema não é no seu arquivo `.jsp`, pelo menos por enquanto.

O mapeamento está trazendo a coluna `cos_id_id` e está dando erro de conversão (para *String*). 
Provavelmente isso está ocorrendo dentro da classe `CosifEntity`.

Verifique como está o mapeamento dela.